# make Ninject resolve ToMethod bindings

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject

I've made a MainFactory which will resolve all dependencies for my classes, but I would like to use Ninject in order to make it automatically resolve constructor parameters.

so, I'm trying to bind the interfaces to my factory's methods like so

```
kernel.Bind<ILoggerContainer>().ToMethod(m => MainFactory.CreateLoggerContainer());
```

but, when I'm binding something that depends on the ILoggerContainer, I need to specify the method to resolve the other container like this

```
kernel.Bind<IUsersContainer>().ToMethod(m => MainFactory.CreateUsersServiceContainer(kernel.Get<ILoggerContainer>()));
```

now I'm sure there's a better way especially since Ninject's main goal is to resolve these dependencies automatically.

**Edit:**
the MainFactory is in a separate project which will contain all dependencies, therefore, if a dependency change, I only need to update its DLL.

the ninject is used so that I can set the constructor to take an implementation of an interface as a parameter, and it gets set automatically,

the main question was how can I make this

```
kernel.Bind<IUsersContainer>().ToMethod(m => MainFactory.CreateUsersServiceContainer(kernel.Get<ILoggerContainer>()));
```

into something like this

```
kernel.Bind<IUsersContainer>().ToMethod(m => MainFactory.CreateUsersServiceContainer());
```

note the parameter of CreateUsersServiceContainer was removed and I'm assuming Ninject can fill its parameter with the proper value (already bound in Ninject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is but what it looks like you are trying to do is use your `MainFactory` class to build all of your other classes, but also use Ninject to build the "second level" dependencies.

To me this seems like a very strange approach. Is there a particular reason you need to have `MainFactory` for composing your top level objects? This would indicate a design problem where one "God object" is used to do many things. You'll also have to change your Ninject bindings and your `MainFactory` methods every time a class needs a new dependency, which kind of defeats the point of using a Dependency Injection framework in the first place.

Is it possible for you to replace `MainFactory` with proper Ninject bindings, perhaps using Ninject providers/factories to build objects if they need certain things at runtime? For example, if your `MainFactory` had something like this:

```
public class MainFactory
{
    public static IFoo CreateFoo(ILogger log)
    {
        return new Foo(log);
    }
}

IFoo foo = MainFactory.CreateFoo(kernel.Get<ILogger>());
```

You could replace this with:

```
kernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<FileLogger>();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
IFoo foo = kernel.Get<IFoo>();
```

which is a very standard Ninject approach. If you need to provide values at runtime then take a look at the [Ninject Factory Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) to do something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string runtimeArg) { ... }
}

public interface FooFactory
{
    IFoo CreateFoo(string runtimeArg);
}

kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
kernel.Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory();
IFooFactory factory = kernel.Get<IFooFactory>();
IFoo foo = factory.CreateFoo("my runtime value");
```

Comment: I haven't thought about what needs to change when I create a new dependency, I suppose you could be right in replacing MainFactory with proper Bindings, I just wanted to leave the design open for adding AOP decorators if needed in the future.